# Send thousands of emails via Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses, zend-mail

I am using Amazon SES to send emails with Zend_Mail and authenticating via SMTP. So far so quiet, but I need to send 20,000 emails, and plan Amazon can already send 35 e-mails per second. The question I have to do something close to 570 requests to send or is there a way in Amazon to send it all to a queue and they manage the cadence of delivery according to plan?

- Detail the subject and content of the emails are personalized for each user.

Thank you,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

you have limited sending your email based on amazon restrictions.

therefore maximum 35 mails per second
and respected daily limit (example 5000 emails per day, knowing that it is a day slippery.). If you started your shipment at 10am and it ends at 12pm. You must wait the next 12 can post a new 5000 mails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that limit will increases gradually...

Just start sending your email and the Daily Quota and Sending Limit will get increases depending upon your e-mail reputation. Means which kind of email you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

While the limits do increase gradually, you can request AWS with a service request to enhance your limits (just like the way you requested to move out of the sandbox region)

AWS will generally respond in a day or so with the enhanced limits. But don't ask for big enhancements from day 1, take it slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a limit increase at amazon by filling an extend access request [extend access request](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/)

Also useful might be to check your current limits by following the steps described [in AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-limits.html)